# Is JSHint a Node.js syntax validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint, jshint

I have come across JSHint but was hoping it would validate node.js syntax but it doesn't, for example if I do:

```
var server = http.createServerfunctionThatDoesNotExists(function(request, response) {....
```

The test passes even though there isn't a function called createServerfunctionThatDoesNotExists

What am I missing with JSHint and the node.js option?

Comment: JSHint validates javascript not APIs. the node.js option just doesnt complain when you reference global or require which would normally be referenceerrors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't dig into CommonJS modules as they can contain virtually everything.

So even if you are `require`'ing `http` it could be your own module with any interface.

'Assume Node' means it tolerates global variables like `module` or `exports`

Answer (score 1):

JSHint is basically JSLint and is more for syntax/style/JS-nonos rather than a deep-scan product that executes your JS. Fully vetting JS code (or any dynamic language, really, depending on your definition of dynamic) pretty much requires running it, since things like methods can be defined more or less anywhere, including at runtime.

JSHint *does* go a bit further and allow the definition of high-level constructs used by *some* JS libraries.